# When the accordion is in the open state, double-clicking on it does not close and then reopen it

Tags: reactjs, accordion, chakra-ui

```
 <AccordionItem {...styles.InformationAccordionItem}>
    <h2>
      <AccordionButton {...styles.InformationAccordionButton}>
                                <Box {...styles.InformationAccordionBox}>
                                    {formatMessage({
                                        defaultMessage: 'Highlights',
                                        id: 'product_detail.accordion.button.HighLights'
                                    })}
                                </Box>
                                <AccordionIcon as={DownwardArrowIcon} w={4} h={2} />
                            </AccordionButton>
                        </h2>
                        <AccordionPanel {...styles.InformationAccordionPanel}>
                            <UnorderedList spacing={2}>
                                {highlightsArray &&
                                    highlightsArray?.map((highlight, index) => (
                                        <ListItem key={index} color={'black'} fontSize={'xs'}>
                                            {highlight}
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}
                            </UnorderedList>


                        </AccordionPanel>
     </AccordionItem>
```

When the accordion is in the open state, double-clicking on it does not close and then reopen it. However, when it is in the closed state, double-clicking works fine.

I want when we double click accordion in open state it should work fine, first close it and then again open it - as we double click it in open state.

I am using Chakara ui library and I can't use jQuery here.

Comment: When you say "I am using", you should add those as tags to your post so the right people get to see your question in their feed. Add as many tags as are relevant. Right now this will be targetted to.. "Accordion" people.

Comment: thanks to guid me, do u have any solution for this

Comment: I do not, as react isn't my forté (or even to my liking, being a layer of developer-friendly stuff that just uses more cycles), and I'm not seeing any reference to double clicking in your code _at all_, so if it's a plugin/library you are using, maybe check their docs to see how this works?

Comment: I don't think u have any idea about it because, double-click is the default functionality of accordion button  but while using the chakra Ui Accordion its not working fine. So in code u can't see any reference.

Comment: Yes, I do know what I am talking about, I just don't know the specifics of your specific accordion - see how I told you to check the docs? And if double clicking is your issue, then the code you are showing doesn't really help. But fine, you have tagged it correctly so let's see if some people with direct experience with the library you are using (who "have idea what u talking about") can help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, it get solve by applying Accordion prop reduceMotion="true"